# ¿Estas expresiones son iguales?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas, trasteando con C# y C++ me he topado con que el siguiente tipo de expresiones es válido:

```
int A, B, C, D, E;
A = B = C = D = E = 1;
```

Según esta acción, estoy asignando 1 en `E`, `E` en `D` y asi, hasta llegar al final.

Mi pregunta *principal* es la siguiente, ¿Por qué este tipo de expresiones es valida?

Según el IL *([Generado por DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Y4q4Y))* al realizar esta acción, obtengo esto:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
// 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (int32 V_0,
                  int32 V_1,
                  int32 V_2,
                  int32 V_3,
                  int32 V_4)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0002:  dup
    IL_0003:  stloc.s    V_4
    IL_0005:  dup
    IL_0006:  stloc.3
    IL_0007:  dup
    IL_0008:  stloc.2
    IL_0009:  dup
    IL_000a:  stloc.1
    IL_000b:  stloc.0
    IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Y el IL generado por la siguiente asignación:

```
A = 0; B = 0; C = 0; D = 0; E = 0;
```

Es el siguiente:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
// 
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init (int32 V_0,
                  int32 V_1,
                  int32 V_2,
                  int32 V_3,
                  int32 V_4)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002:  stloc.0
    IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0004:  stloc.1
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0006:  stloc.2
    IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0008:  stloc.3
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000a:  stloc.s    V_4
    IL_000c:  ret
}
```

No entiendo mucho de IL pero según el código anterior, el método que asigna una variable en otra, ocupa más espacio en memoria y así, o algo parecido *(Favor corregirme si estoy mal)*.

Mi duda es, ¿Ambos códigos realmente realizan lo mismo?

Comment: En el segundo caso no deberías tratar de asignar las variables a 1 para que el resultado sea el mismo?

Comment: La duda surgió al intentar asignarlas a cero, no había intentado otros valores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A continuación la explicación del IL del primer caso

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
// 
    .maxstack  2                  // Denota que la pila tendrá máximo 2 elementos
    .locals init (int32 V_0,      // Declara las 5 variables de tipo Int32
                  int32 V_1,
                  int32 V_2,
                  int32 V_3,
                  int32 V_4)
    IL_0000:  nop                 // Autogenerado cuando se compila como DEBUG
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1            // Se coloca en la pila el valor 1
    IL_0002:  dup                 // Se duplica el valor 1 en la pila como segundo elemento
    IL_0003:  stloc.s    V_4      // Se desapila el segundo 1 y se almacena en la variable V_4 (E)
    IL_0005:  dup                 // Se duplica de nuevo el valor 1
    IL_0006:  stloc.3             // Se desapila el tercer 1 y se almacena en la variable 3 (V_3/D)
    IL_0007:  dup                 // Se duplica en valor 1 en la pila
    IL_0008:  stloc.2             // Se desapila el cuarto 1 y se almacena en la variable 2 (V_2/C)
    IL_0009:  dup                 // Se duplica el valor 1 en la pila
    IL_000a:  stloc.1             // Se desapila el quinto 1 y se amancena en la variable 1 (V_1/B)
    IL_000b:  stloc.0             // Se desapila el primer 1 y se apila en la variable 0 (V_0/A)
    IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

En este caso el algortimo que se sigue es colocar el valor `1` en la pila y luego ir duplicando ese valor para almacenarlo tempralmente para poder seguir adignandolo después de asignarselo a la variable correspondiente, primero a `V_5` luego a `V_4` y así hasta que no se necesita almacenar temporalmente más la variable, al final la pila se queda vacía y l valor `1` asignado a todas las variables

En el segundo caso asumiendo que la expresión era: `A = 1; B = 1; C = 1; D = 1; E = 1;`

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
// 
    .maxstack  1                  // Se define el tamaño máximo de pila en 1
    .locals init (int32 V_0,      // Se declaran las 5 variables de tipo Int32
                  int32 V_1,
                  int32 V_2,
                  int32 V_3,
                  int32 V_4)
    IL_0000:  nop                // Generado al compilar como DEBUG
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1           // Se apila el valor 1
    IL_0002:  stloc.0            // Se desapila el 1 y se asigna a la variable 0 (V_0/A)
    IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1           // Se apila el valor 1
    IL_0004:  stloc.1            // Se desapila el 1 y se asigna a la variable 1 (V_1/B)
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1           // Se apila el valor 1
    IL_0006:  stloc.2            // Se desapila el 1 y se asigna a la variable 2 (V_2/C)
    IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1           // Se apila el valor 1
    IL_0008:  stloc.3            // Se desapila el 1 y se asigna a la variable 3 (V_3/D)
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1           // Se apila el valor 1
    IL_000a:  stloc.s    V_4     // Se desapila el 1 y se asigna a V_4 (E)
    IL_000c:  ret
}
```

En este caso el algortimo simplemento consiste en apilar el valor 1 y asignarlo a la varible correspondiente. Esto se repite 5 veces.

Como podemos observar en este caso en la pila solo se tiene a la vez un elemento, ya que seimpre se apila y se desapila inmediatamente, en el caso anterior se tenian hasta dos `1` ya que se duplicaba el mismo valor cada vez en vez de apilar un mismo valor 5 veces.

Ahora respondiendo a porque es válida la primera sintaxis en C# se debe a lo siguiente

El [`= Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sbkb459w.aspx) tiene un valor de retorno y es el mismo valor que se asigna a la variable del lado izquierdo, es decir:

```
A = B = C = D = E = 1;
```

equivale a

```
A = (B = (C = (D = (E = 1))));
```

y ejecutandolo paso a paso:

```
A = (B = (C = (D = (E = 1))));    // E == 1
...
A = (B = (C = (D = 1)));          // E == 1, D == 1
...
A = (B = (C = 1));                // E == 1, D == 1, C == 1
...
A = (B = 1);                      // E == 1, D == 1, C == 1, B == 1
...
A = 1;                            // E == 1, D == 1, C == 1, B == 1, A == 1
```

Comment: Excelente explicación del código IL

Answer (score 2):

```
int A, B, C, D, E;
A = B = C = D = E = 1;
```

> Mi pregunta principal es la siguiente, ¿Por qué este tipo de
>   expresiones es valida?

La segunda sentencia contiene múltiples *expresiones de asignación*, una expresión de asignación asigna un valor a una variable:

```
A = 1;
```

Pero ese valor puede ser una expresión de asignación por sí mismo:

```
A = B = 1;
```

Primero se evalúa la expresión de asignación `B = 1` que resulta en `1` y ese valor se asigna a `A`. El mismo proceso se repite para todas las variables en la cadena de asignaciones.

Esto lo encontramos en la [especificación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315.aspx) del lenguaje 7.13.1

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
>   the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and
>   is always classified as a value.

A nivel de IL el código es diferente, sin embargo el resultado es el mismo al asignar el mismo valor a todas las variables.

```
A = 1; B = 1; C = 1; D = 1; E = 1;
```

Comment: Y como se llama a eso _Aparte de "asignación"_, cuando digo: `A = B = 1`?

Comment: No creo que tenga un nombre especial, de la misma forma que no hay un nombre para `A + B + C + D` solo le llamamos suma, yo me referiría a una sentencia `A = B = 1` como _asignación múltiple_ o algo similar.

Comment: En adición a lo último, si es cierto que el resultado es lo mismo, pero según veo, uno es mas eficiente que otro en cuanto a rendimiento, no?